# setCardview Background color to match the response that I get from Json

Tags: android, json

I would like to make a cardview Background color match the color that my api provided.

Here is my item_details.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0.01dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tvMenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMenu"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#ff444444"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have two parameter in my cardview, which is image and text.
So basically, color which i get from the api, gonna set to Imageview, and details, gonna show in my textview.

Here is my api result,

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Item 1",
    "colorMenu": "#666666"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Item 2",
    "colorMenu": "#336699"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Item 3",
    "colorMenu": "#663399"
  }
]
```

I've sucessfully, get the response "Name", and show it in my cardview.
But, when I try to put in the color this errors, show up.

**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""**

here is my onBindViewHolder on myAdapter

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
 holder.mName.setText(itemList.get(position).getNmMenu());
 holder.mColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(String.valueOf(itemList.get(position).getColorMenu())));

    }
```

Here is My Object

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MyObject {

@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("colorMenu")
@Expose
private String colorMenu;

/**
* 
* @return
* The name
*/
public String getName() {
return name;
}

/**
* 
* @param name
* The Name
*/
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The colorMenu
*/
public String getColorMenu() {
return colorMenu;
}

/**
* 
* @param colorMenu
* The colorMenu
*/
public void setColorMenu(String colorMenu) {
this.colorMenu = colorMenu;
}

}
```

Comment: can you show the method getColorMenu() ?

Comment: what this returns `itemList.get(position).getNmMenu()` ?

Comment: It will be much better if you will create a pojo class and then set background color  like this holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(item.getColor));

Comment: @Mr.7 it returns 3 cardview with each name, Item 1 , Item 2 , Item 3

Comment: @NiteshKumar you mean using the model object from this link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: yeah you can do it that way or you can create yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making color for my first object color in my json.

and getting the result, and its working with this code

```
holder.mColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(itemList.get(position).getColorMenu()));
```

Thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of `colorMenu = ""`

`Color.parseColor()` should not be empty

apply the background color iff colorMenu not empty

```
if (String.valueOf(itemList.get(position).getColorMenu()) != null) {
    holder.mColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(String.valueOf(itemList.get(position).getColorMenu())));
}
```

Comment: The error you are getting from onBindViewHolder's last line only. so
split `Color.parseColor(String.valueOf(itemList.get(position).getColorMenu()))` into multiple lines like
`String colorVal = String.valueOf(itemList.get(position).getColorMenu())` 
and debug line by line

Answer (score 0):

after you get your jsonObject from colorMenu, try this

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorMenu));
```

hope this helping

Comment: i've tried that, but it didnt work. still got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

try this if it is useful.

> holder.mColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.decode((itemList.get(position).getColorMenu()));